# web service using soap and wsdl is not working php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a web service using wdsl and soap. The server is to be written in php.

As of now I am trying out things by adding just one function to the soap server object. My requirement is that this function should take an associative array. Right now it returns a string but its just trial for now and will also be returning an array as per requirement.

For taking an assoc array as input I defined a complexType in the wsdl.
Following is the code

```
<types>
  <xsd:schema 
  targetNamespace="http://projects.kp/test/webservice/StoreService.wsdl"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema/">
     <xsd:complexType name="store">
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" /> 
        <xsd:element name="subdomain" type="xsd:string" /> 
     </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>  
<message name="StoreRequest">
  <part name="store" type="tns:store"/>
</message>
<message name="StoreResponse">
  <part name="url" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

When I run the soap client file in the browser, it gives the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: 
[WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected in complexType
```

If I use a string datatype instead of a complexType, it works properly.
I guess i haven't yet understood how complexTypes work so I am unable to debug this.

Also I would like to know if array as the request and response type will work if
the client is coded in some other language say .NET.

(Right now I am testing this on a virtual host on a ubuntu desktop and the server and client are on the same vhost and both written in php)

Thanks

Comment: Is this your WSDL?Why are you using `type` in the `part` of the message element?This is used in RPC/Encoding.Are you using RPC or doc/literal?If you use doc instead replace to `<part name="store" element="tns:store"/>`.Also is tns prefix bind to the targerNamespace?

Comment: hi thanks for replying. yes its my WSDL. how do i know if its RPC or doc/literal! sorry, silly question but i am referring to different online tutorials and resources for doing this. and i did try "element" instead of "type" as per one tutorial i came across but it didnt help and caused confusion instead. Also I couldn't find a solid reference that explains basics, so a good link would really help a lot. thanks

Comment: If the `part` child of `message` has the attribute `type` it means RPC endoding and this should be also mentioned in the binding section. If the `part` child of `message` has the attribute `element` this means it is doc and is also mentioned as doc in the binding. A good description of the differences is here (although not recent but still good) http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/

Comment: ok I changed the style to document but it still shows an error. but now its `[WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected in elemet`. What i need to do is that the function added to the soap server should take an associative array as an argument and should return an associative array. When I `var_dump($client->__getFunctions());` it shows both return type and argument type as string. What am I missing here ? The entire xml can be found on paste bin here http://paste-bin.com/view/b111c956 . Thanks

Comment: solved it using rpc style itself. i had made some very silly mistakes in the wsdl. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to set **xsd:all** or **xsd:sequence** before **xsd:element**